# Program automatically starts itself when it shouldn't under windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-registry

Running windows 7 pro, I have a user (lets call him player) that is locked down and uses a custom shell script, that runs a couple programs on login and doesn't load explorer.

I have another user (config user) that is almost entirely locked down. It doesn't have access to the file system except for 1 or 2 files, and its purpose is giving access to sound and networking settings, which it has links to from the desktop. This user shouldn't be able to launch the application in question.

Now, if I log in player, and immediately log him out, before the spinner goes awa... like, the application launches, spinner still spinning, logout, back to login screen, then log in config, config user loads desktop, *and then application launches*.

???? What's going on? it's not running the entire shell script. just the one application re-launches after switching users. if I wait 10 seconds after loading player before logging out, it doesn't happen. I didn't write the program myself, if there are sneaky things a program can do to enqueue a re-launch, that's a possibility. Finally, I want to prevent this behavior, are there any registry settings that might allow me to lock this out?

Thanks

Edit:

By locked down I mean I use judicious use of group policy to disable most functionality of windows. there are no options on the start menu, ctrl alt del menu has nothing other than restart, the file system is locked out, access denied. the desktop is locked. window r doesn't work. the only way to get to anything is several icons on the desktop that go to control panel functions of sound, networking, and display settings. the user is technically an 'admin' by user group, but has only access to those few functions.

Comment: Might just be a poorly written script.

Comment: Perhaps! I'm looking into that, and I'm running `sc start player conductor` which is a watchdog service it has that will relaunch it. Indeed, when I log in the new user, player conductor shows up first, then the player.

Comment: Can you [edit] and define *locked down*?

Comment: Sure. I did that. wondering if I can add a logout script to kill a starting service. or where the service task queue goes, since the service queues running conductor as system, then that executes even when you load another user? seems pretty weird.